# jsoup remove outer html tag - code HTML element

Tags: html, jsoup, pre

This seems pretty straightforward but, obviously I'm doing something wrong.  Here is my HTML - I am trying to create both singular code tags and nested code tags under pre tags - the resulting content will be "one line boxes with code inside" and also with the pre tags "big boxes with code inside".  There are also empty paragraph tags that I can't get rid of using the standard methods - element remove after testing for no Text in the paragraph.  Here's the input

```
        <h1>Module Description and Learning Objectives</h1>  
        <p> 
        </p> 
        <pre>                
        <p>
        <code>2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 -</code>
        </p>
        <p>
        <code>2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 - sects.title</code>
        </p>
        <p>
        <code>2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 - sects.id=1</code>
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        </pre> 
        <p>Sentence 1</p> 
        <p> 
        <code>System.out.println("id:"+element.attr("id"));</code> 
        </p> 
        <p>Sentence 2</p> 
        <p> 
        <code>System.out.println("src:"+element.attr("src"));</code> 
        </p> 
        <p>Sentence 3</p> 
        <p> 
        <code>System.out.println("alt:"+element.attr("alt"));</code> 
        </p> 
        <p> 
        </p>
```

This is my code (don't follow names as much as constructs, mid-code names   :)

```
          Elements pWithCodeTagList = docXMLformat.select("code");
          if (pWithCodeTagList.size() > 0) {
              for (Element pTag : pWithCodeTagList) {
                   System.out.println("pTag=" + pTag.text() + " " + pTag.tagName());
                   pTag.unwrap();
              }
          }
```

Here is the output in eclipse - I am indeed selecting the code tags and expecting the parent p to disappear

```
 pTag=2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 - code
 pTag=2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 - sects.title code
 pTag=2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 - sects.id=1 code
 pTag=System.out.println("id:"+element.attr("id")); code
 pTag=System.out.println("src:"+element.attr("src")); code
 pTag=System.out.println("alt:"+element.attr("alt")); code
```

This is the result:  I expected the paragraph tags to disappear, not the code tags!

```
   <h1>Module Description and Learning Objectives</h1> 
                <p> 
                </p> 
                <pre>                
                    <p>
                    2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 -
                </p>
                    <p>
                    2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 - sects.title
                </p>
                    <p>
                    2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 - sects.id=1
                </p>
                    <p>
                    </p>
                </pre> 
                <p>Sentence 1</p> 
                <p> System.out.println("id:"+element.attr("id")); </p> 
                <p>Sentence 2</p> 
                <p> System.out.println("src:"+element.attr("src")); </p> 
                <p>Sentence 3</p> 
                <p> System.out.println("alt:"+element.attr("alt")); </p> 
                <p> 
                </p>
```

I already touch this area of my document, I've removed a span tag around the code tag prior to this, and had to remove all the line control characters from the line content, maybe PRE and CODE don't work like other tags - I know they are not supposed to, but ...   also, I'm trying to keep the tags and content on the same line so my "code boxes" are as slim as possible, towit:

```
 <pre>                
 <code>2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 -</code>
 <code>2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 - sects.title</code>
 <code>2020-02-13 12:49:15 DEBUG StackTraceElement:48 - sects.id=1</code>
  </pre> 
  <p>Sentence 1</p> 
  <code>System.out.println("id:"+element.attr("id"));</code> 
  <p>Sentence 2</p> 
  <code>System.out.println("src:"+element.attr("src"));</code> 
  <p>Sentence 3</p> 
  <code>System.out.println("alt:"+element.attr("alt"));</code>
```

Comment: From docs : "unwrap​() - 
Removes the matched elements from the DOM, and moves their children up into their parents." I would say this is the expected behaviour isn't it?. Just try and select the elements to get rid of (the p's).

Comment: Hi - YES - you are absolutely correct in your analysis, I was thinking "the present gets unwrapped, select the present and unwrap (remove) the paper (outer layer) but instead it seems be "select the wrapping paper and remove it" - the answer below adds more so I'm selecting it as the answer, but kudos to you for being correct, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is selecting the `code` elements, not the `p` elements, which is why they're getting removed. You should select the `p` elements that have a `code` tag, and `unwrap()` those. [`p:has(code)`](https://try.jsoup.org/~0ocgGLCG07tjPevGa827HUm22Mw)

Also, you don't need to iterate them and call unwrap on each if you want to unwrap them all (unless you want to do extra logic for each one). You can just call [`Elements#upwrap()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#unwrap--)

```
Elements pWithCodeTagList = docXMLformat.select("p:has(code)");
pWithCodeTagList.unwrap();
```

And to find the empty `p` tags, you could use the `:matches` selector which does a regex over the text, and just look for spaces or nothing: [`p:matches(^\s?$)`](https://try.jsoup.org/~r-0OZ4I5vhk4g_3NSWHP17nACXk)

```
Elements emptyPs = docXMLformat.select("p:matches(^\\s?$)");
emptyPs.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks so much - your 4 lines of code solved all my issues!